# SSRS mailing labels with images

Tags: sql-server, image, reporting-services

i want to be able to display a grid of business cards with an image of an employee in SSRS SQL 2008.

For this I have created a query pulling the following data from Employee table:

1. EmployeeID
2. EmployeeName
3. EmployeeImage

The images are stored directly in the database.

I have created a blank report, formatted it to have 3 columns (re sized it to a fairly small size), inserted a table and deleted all the cells except for one. I have added EmployeeID and EmployeeName into the cell. When run, the report displays exactly what i want: grid of employees with their ID and Name.

In order to display the image, I have added another cell to the original one-cell table and inserted the image control into it. The "Use this field" value of the image is

```
=First(Fields!EmployeeImage.Value, "Employees")
```

The inserted image is a jpeg, thus the MIME type is set to image/jpeg.

When i run this, i still get the list of Employees details as before, however the cell, where the image is to be displayed is empty.

Does anyone have any tips on how to achieve what i am looking for?

Thanks

PS: I have googled this without a luck

Comment: How is the image stored in database (Employee - EmployeeImage) ? And for the `Image Control` what source did you choose (guessing `Database`) ?

Comment: there is a table called      Employee, Property      EmplyeeImage of     dataType image. Yes, the source is Database

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer.

For some reason, i was being offered

```
=First(Fields!EmployeeImage.Value, "Employees")
```

under "Use this field".

When i typed in EmployeeImage, it started working.

No idea why this happened though.